tailwindcss darkmode define for react native
I want to set up light and dark mode color configurations for twrnc and tailwindcss so that I can define colors like this:
const colors = {
  light: {
    red: {
      100: "#880808",
      ...
    }
  },
  dark: {
    red: {
      100: "red",
      ...
    }
 },

}

I want to define like this,then using
<View style={tw`bg-red`}>...</View>

How to config it?
Environment
"twrnc": "^4.3.0",
 "tailwindcss": "^3.4.4",

